# Do .rpm files have metadata

Tags: centos, rpm, package-management, packages

I have a .rpm file on my windows machine. Is there a way to inspect this file (either on windows or centos) without installing it, to find out where it was compiled from? something like metadata?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They have lots of metadata. Use `-qp` to target the package file and `--qf` to specify which metadata you're interested in.

```
$ rpm -qp /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/fedora/packages/db4-4.8.30-3.fc15.i686.rpm --qf "%{name}: %{buildhost}\n"
db4: x86-10.phx2.fedoraproject.org
```

`rpm --querytags` will show you the metadata tags.

Comment: Any way to do that on a Windows machine (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: @Mark: There's [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpmwin32/), but I doubt it supports the new hash format.

Answer (score 8):

To check metadata on windows machine - you will need rpm utility. You can run RPM utility on Windows via Cygwin: http://cygwin.com/ - then from cygwin console you can run `rpm -qip /path/file.rpm`

On centos - `rpm -qip /path/file.rpm`

Comment: This displays all of the metadata - just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I've forked @Ignacio answer and created oneliner to quickly go over all tags:

```
rpm -qp package.rpm --qf "$(rpm --querytags | sed -nr 's/(.*)/\1:%{\1}/p' | tr '[:space:]' '\n')"
```